# Fitting Gameobjects within camera view

Tags: unity, camera

[image]I am trying to fit a grid of gameobject into the orthographic view but I have a problem whenever I change the amount of grids to display it would overlap the view.

What cαn I do to fit a series of gameobjects, having always the same margin as the amount of grid changes?

```
private void Start() {
    for(int i = 0; i < wordSearch.Gridsize; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < wordSearch.Gridsize; j++) {
            cell = Instantiate(gridCell, new Vector3(j * 1 * gridCell.transform.position.x * cellSpacing, i * 1 * gridCell.transform.position.y * cellSpacing, 0), Quaternion.identity);
            cell.name = "cell-Y: " + i.ToString() + " cell-X: " + j.ToString();
            GameObject textObject = cell.transform.GetChild(0).gameObject;
            textObject.GetComponent<TextMeshPro>().text = wordSearch.matrix[i, j].ToString();
            textObject.name = textObject.GetComponent<TextMeshPro>().text;
        }
    }
    CenterPoint();
   // FitToScreen();
}

private void CenterPoint() {
    Vector3 offset = new Vector3(0, -1, -10);
    cellGameobject = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("cell");
    transformCell = new Transform[cellGameobject.Length];
    for(int i = 0; i < cellGameobject.Length; i++) {
        transformCell[i] = cellGameobject[i].transform;
    }
    for(int a = 0; a < transformCell.Length; a++) {
        cellVectors += transformCell[a].position;
    }
    centercell = cellVectors / transformCell.Length;
    GetComponent<Camera>().transform.position = centercell + offset;
}

private void FitToScreen() {
    Camera.main.orthographicSize = /* Insert Comment */
}
```

Comment: I dont know the answer for you but i've also struggled in the past with the same thing. Firstly though, I wonder why you multiply by 1 on the Instantiate of a cell ? (Surely that has no effect?) . Also you don't need the .ToString() when you create the cell names because you've already used the string to make "cell-Y" and so simply "cell-Y: " + i + "cell-x ....etc.etc, will give you the same result. Thats just a little sidenote, I cant offer anything much on setting the camera view. I would say that of course the screen-width will obviously need to be set to cell-width * GridSize.x + margin.

Comment: hope its some help to you whilst waiting on proper answers

Comment: @SuperMegaBroBro I'll add those to my changes. Thanks for enlightenment.